# PHP openssl_sign_csr with x509 attributes

Tags: php, openssl, cryptography, certificate, csr

I have a script that generates CSRs and can integrate with windows CA to sign, but I want to have the option to sign with a local CA, so I was using the openssl_sign_csr function. And it is signing the certificates, however, it does not retain the x509 attributes (namely, extended key usage and subject alternative names).

I pass it the config file and I've tried a few samples that I've found on the internet, the key things that im including is the `copy_extensions = copy` and `x509_extensions = usr_cert` with the usr_cert block having:

```
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
subjectAltName=email:copy
```

however, any mix of config that doesn't result in an error does not carry across any of the extensions. the above applied the email field to the SAN instead. i cannot find a copy option. but also, I'd like to have it apply the CN field if the SAN is not specified.

I know the CSR has them because when signed by certsrv it carries them.

Would love some insight from anyone that has gotten this working in the past.
(also, key usage will be for server identification, rarely client identification, if that makes any difference to it)

Comment: Why don't you just set the value you want to `subjectAltName`?

Comment: this is what im trying to do.... thats literally what the post is about...  this is for the signing authority. it needs to copy the subjectAltName thats defined in the CSR (and ultimately i'd like to copy the CN into it too incase its not there)  but its not copying the x509 attributes across from the CSR to the signed cert.

Comment: Since you generated the CSR, you already know the value of the subjectAltName. You don't need to extract it from the CSR.

Comment: not always, some devices generate their own csr and I need to extract from that to inject into the SAN or even just honour the SAN that is supplied in the CSR because it just drops the SAN if its not specified in the signing config file for some weird reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy_extensions` option can be used with the command-line version of OpenSSL. It doesn't seem possible
to use it with the PHP OpenSSL extension.

As a workaround, you can extract the informations you need from the CSR. It is possible to do so with the help of
the [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) library (as mentioned [here](https://phpseclib.com/docs/csr)):

```php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
use phpseclib3\File\X509;

function getCsrData(string $csrFile): array
{
    $csr = file_get_contents($csrFile);
    if(!$csr)
        throw new Exception('CSR not found');

    $x509 = new X509();
    if(!$x509->loadCSR($csr))
        throw new Exception('Invalid CSR');

    // Get the Common Name
    $data['CN'] = $x509->getDNProp('CN')[0];

    // Get the Subject Alternative Name
    $SAN = $x509->getExtension('id-ce-subjectAltName');
    if($SAN)
    {
        $arr = [];
        foreach($SAN as $val)
            $arr[] = 'DNS:' . $val['dNSName'];
        $data['subjectAltName'] = implode(', ', $arr);
    }

    // Get the Extended Key Usage
    $XKU = $x509->getExtension('id-ce-extKeyUsage');
    if($XKU)
    {
        $arr = [];
        foreach($XKU as $val)
            $arr[] = substr($val, 6);
        $data['extKeyUsage'] = implode(', ', $arr);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Example of a CSR generation:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout test.key -out test.csr -config test.cnf
```

with the following config file (test.cnf):

```
[req]
distinguished_name = dn
req_extensions = req_ext
prompt = no

[dn]
CN = www.domain.com

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = DNS:www.domain.com, DNS:domain.com
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
```

The CSR is parsed like this:

```php
$data = getCsrData('test.csr');
var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'CN' => 'www.domain.com',
  'subjectAltName' => 'DNS:www.domain.com, DNS:domain.com',
  'extKeyUsage' => 'serverAuth',
)
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I will give this a crack tonight. pulling from CSR was a path i went down but didnt know/think to use the alternate library, the built in openssl_csr_get_subject doesn't cover the x509 extensions which was a pita but your config examples look to do exactly what I want to do. 

Will update as i progress :)

Comment: legend, this was the go. processed the SAN IP and DNS entries and attached them to the config file.

Thanks for that :)

Comment: one more Q. i have been looking through the phpseclib docs, it throws a typeerror if there is no extension section on the CSR. i tried using x509->getExtensions() but that also throws a type error. 

any suggestions on how to catch that one?

Comment: found it, 
getAttributes returns `array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "pkcs-9-at-extensionRequest" }` when the extension is present, the array is empty otherwise. that seems to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you out:

```
<?php


$csr = file_get_contents('<your csr path and file>.csr');


$config = array(
    'config' => '<openssl path configuration file>.cnf', // openssl config path
    'digest_alg' => 'sha256', // hash algo
    'x509_extensions' => 'usr_cert', // X.509 extension
    'req_extensions' => 'req_ext', //  CSR extension
    'private_key_bits' => 2048, // Key size
);


$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new($config);


$signedCert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privateKey, 365, $config, time());


openssl_x509_export($signedCert, $certOut);


echo $certOut;

?>
```

Comment: thats what i was doing originally but it seems like the csr_sign wants/needs a different config array/file to copy the extensions across. its been a while since i was tinkering so i'll have another crack to be sure

Comment: no bueno. 

my usr_cert section of config file looks like :
    [ usr_cert ]
    basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
    nsComment= "Testing"
    subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
    authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
    subjectAltName=email:copy


with this, it applies the SAN as `RFC822 Name=test@domain.local` (what was supplied in the CSR to the email field)

i cant find details around what it will accept in that san field but commonName doesnt work nor does dns (with or without :copy)  i haven't found any docs that are clear except for overwriting them. :/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may just be an issue with getting the right extensions configured.  For example copy_extensions = copy and x509_extensions = usr_cert settings should be under the "CA_default" section of your config file.

If's usually the small things that get you, e.g., openssl_csr_sign won't work right if you don't have a valid openssl.cnf installed for this function.

And if all else fails, there's always Command-Line OpenSSL, e.g.,

openssl x509 -req -in yourcsr.csr -CA yourca.crt -CAkey yourcakey.key -CAcreateserial -out yourcert.crt -days 365 -extfile yourconfig.cnf -extensions usr_cert

You can also manually extract the attributes from the CSR and include them in the signing command. Use the openssl req -noout -text -in yourcsr.csr command to view the attributes in the CSR and then manually add them to the yourconfig.cnf file under the "usr_cert" section.

It could be helpful to try alternative libraries like phpseclib, e.g., use the setExtensionCopy(true) method to ensure your x509 extensions are copied from the CSR to the signed certificate correctly.

Comment: yea its been a pain. its definitely accepting the config file, if i specify subjectaltname in the usr_cert section it applies whats specified there (either static value or email:copy, why on earth isnt there a csr copy or CN copy option????) 

i thought about doing exec cli option but as i've deployed in a docker environment, cli commands arent sustainable/viable :/ 

ill keep plugging and will go down the phpseclib path for next options. thanks :)